# How can I rewrite "I have opened console in my Ubuntu. I have written command tty." as a single sentence?

Tags: past-tense

I would like to say two actions that have been performed once in the past:

> I have opened console in my Ubuntu.
>   I have written command tty.

Is it correct to write both actions in one sentence like written below?

> I have opened console in Linux and have written command tty.

Is it good from point of tenses rules?

Comment: You can omit the second have: *I have opened a console in Linux and written a command tty.*

Comment: @vico I edited the title of your question based on my guess. Feel free to edit it or roll it back if it doesn't mean what you want to ask.

Comment: Off-topic: I think, you're missing some preposition (`in`/`into`/`on`/`onto`) between the words `command` and `tty`, aren't you?

Comment: I opened a console in Linux and wrote a command tty.

Comment: @Subjunctive You can omit **have** as well. **I opened** is past tense.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know. Since no time frame is given, both can work. But I think the OP wanted to stick with the perfect tense.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here that need some work. The construction 'I have ____' is the present perfect, which has an unusual tone to a native American English speaker.  Usually we use the present perfect to say something happened at some undetermined time in the past, rather than an action you have just done.

*'I have flown in an airplane'* implies that you have done it at some point, but maybe not recently.  I think the simple past is what you're looking for here. Like '*I flew in an airplane*' which implies that the action is completed.

Also, both console and command here are direct objects, which means you need to use a **determiner** or **article** in most cases.  The correct way of saying this would be:

I opened the console in Ubuntu/Linux and wrote the command tty.

Also, like modulusshift says, generally when "writing" in a terminal we use the verb to type.

Answer (score 0):

> I typed tty into the terminal.

Does that work?

Comment: I think it works, although the question specifies Ubuntu. Something like I typed `tty` into the terminal in Ubuntu would be more apt.